# Callbacks of Gtk Radio Buttons in Julia

Tags: callback, radio-button, gtk, julia, signals

I'm trying to revive and old code of mine, which used radio buttons in Julia. However, callbacks don't seem to work (similar callbacks to checkboxes and buttons *do* work). Here's a minimal example:

```
using Gtk

function test()
    win = GtkWindow("Radio Button Test")
    vbox = GtkBox(:v)
    push!(win, vbox)
    choices = ["first", "second", "third", "fourth"]
    radios = [GtkRadioButton(choice) for choice in choices]
    set_gtk_property!(radios[1], :active, true)
    for r in radios
        set_gtk_property!(r, :group, radios[1])
        signal_connect(r, "toggled") do _
            warn_dialog("Changed to: $(choices[findfirst(radios, r)])")
        end
        push!(vbox, r)
    end
    showall(win)
    nothing
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: I have updated to the latest version (Julia 1.4.1 with Gtk 1.1.3), but the problem persists, i.e., the callback function does not seem to be called when I click on the radio buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was not a real issue - the problem was with the callback function: `findfirst` cannot be used like this anymore, so there was an (invisible) error.
Changing the callback to

```
warn_dialog("Changed to: $(get_gtk_property(r, :label, AbstractString))")
```

it works as expected.